# Pandas sort DataFrame based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in the format shown below:

```
Id    Name    Mag    Out      Des

23    Yah     1.0    base     n-0
23    Yah     1.0    base     n-0
23    Yah     1.0    base     n-0
24    Nah     0.99   base     n-0
24    Nah     1.01   line-2   line-2
24    Nah     0.95   line-3   line-3
24    Nah     1.1    line-4   line-4
25    lol     1.0    line-1   line-1
25    lol     1.1    line-3   line-3
25    lol     0.9    line-4   line-4
25    lol     0.95   line-5   line-5
```

The output has to meet the following conditions:

1. For the same ID and Name, if "out" column has only base then report the item only once corresponding to the first row.
2. For the same ID and Name, if "out" column has at-least one base item then report the row corresponding to the base and the minimum and maximum of "Mag" column.

The output has to be in the following format:

```
Id    Name    Mag    Out      Des

23    Yah     1.0    base     n-0
24    Nah     0.99   base     n-0
24    Nah     0.95   line-3   line-3
24    Nah     1.1    line-4   line-4
25    lol     0.9    line-4   line-4
25    lol     0.95   line-5   line-5
25    lol     1.0    line-1   line-1
25    lol     1.1    line-3   line-3
```

Comment: Is there an actual issue? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: For ID / Name combinations that have only "base" - which row should be maintained?

Comment: @Roy2012 maintain the first row data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it. In several steps, for clarity:

```
def check_base(x):
    if all([elem == "base" for elem in x]):
        return ["keep"] + ["drop"] * (len(x)-1)
    elif "base" in list(x):
        return ["keep" if i=="base" else "maybe" for i in list(x)]
    else:
        return "keep"

df["criteria"] = df.groupby(["Id", "Name"], as_index = False).Out.transform(check_base)

g_min = df.groupby(["Id", "Name"]).Mag.transform("min")
g_max = df.groupby(["Id", "Name"]).Mag.transform("max")

df = df[(df.criteria == "keep") | (df.criteria == "maybe") & ((df.Mag == g_min) | (df.Mag == g_max))]
```

The result is:

```
    Id Name   Mag     Out     Des criteria
0   23  Yah  1.00    base     n-0     keep
3   24  Nah  0.99    base     n-0     keep
5   24  Nah  0.95  line-3  line-3    maybe
6   24  Nah  1.10  line-4  line-4    maybe
7   25  lol  1.00  line-1  line-1     keep
8   25  lol  1.10  line-3  line-3     keep
9   25  lol  0.90  line-4  line-4     keep
10  25  lol  0.95  line-5  line-5     keep
```